# Using Custom Controllers within Visualforce Email Templates

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, visualforce-template

I am trying to create a VisualForce Email Template, in this emailTemplate i need to get value from Custom Objects.(This Object is not related to Any other Objects - This is the Object Which i am storing the Configuration values)

Below are the Apex Class, Controller, and VF Email Template. I am Receiving the empty data email.

**APEX:**

```
public class getSiteURL {
    private Configure__c config; 
    public string getSiteURL() {        
        config = [select Configuration_Value__c from Configure__c where Configuration_Type__c LIKE 'Site URL'];
        
        return config.PSAS__Configuration_Value__c;
    }    
}
```

**VF Components** -- `siteURLComponents`

```
<apex:component  controller="getSiteURL" access="global">
</apex:component>
```

**VisualForce Email Template**

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="test" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Family__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<html>
<body>
<b><u>URL:</u></b>
        <br />
        <c:siteURLComponents/>
</body>
</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your component you need to use the variable you are not using it. Also I suggest you as better practice use Proper name for controller and follow proper naming conventions.

```
<apex:component  controller="getSiteURL" access="global">
    {!SiteURL}
</apex:component>
```

Comment: Thanks @tushar , Facing One more issue I am trying to add this string in href in the VF Email Template like this `href='<c:siteURLComponents />/school?id={!relatedTo.key}'` When I do the Send Test and Verify Getting link like this https://Qwertd-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/email/%3Cc:siteURLComponents%20/%3E/school?id=324ctfgdty57yrtfgh54

Comment: I suggest you to create this anchor tag in component itself.

Comment: Tried by adding ` <a href="{!SiteURL}"></a>` in Component, Still facing same Issue.